# O que é uma Intent no código em java/android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Dentro de um código escrito no Android Studio pois estou aprendendo desenvolvimento mobile e estou encontrando problemas com alguns termos e como achei dificuldade em encontrar as respostas resolvi perguntar aqui.

Comment: A documentação não ajudou? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Answer (score 1):

Um intent (em português: intenção) é um objeto que encapsula a ideia de uma descrição de uma ação a ser executada.

É um objeto e não uma String ou parâmetro semelhante por dois motivos, porque assim guarda mais informações e porque precisa ser transmitido de um componente para outro do sistema (tanto que implementa a interface Parcelable).

Talvez os idealizadores da API pudessem tê-la chamado de IntendedAction ("ação que se pretende executar").

Ela é propositalmente abstrata (de forma que o usuário possa escolher qual ação exata tomar, por exemplo).

Por exemplo, a intenção de abrir uma Activity ou tela nova (seu uso mais significativo).

Basicamente é um objeto passivo contendo algumas informações, em particular as que são necessárias para orientar o sistema a abrir uma atividade, se comunicar com um serviço, etc.

A [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) (em particular o [Guia do Desenvolvedor](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)) dá outros detalhes.